# Is the Symfony Redis Cache adapter using atomic transactions by default?

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I'm trying to deploy a distributed service architecture using Symfony.

My question is if I can rely on the Redis Cache adapter to read/write in an atomic matter? If a service needs to register itself in the serialized services array, no other service should try to register itself in the meantime given it will delete the initial service from the array.

Should I use the Symfony Lock to avoid race conditions on the same cache key?

Stack: php8.0, php-redis8.0

Comment: Seems you are looking for `isolation` here, which [Redis](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas) provides with the [WATCH](https://redis.io/commands/watch) keyword, isolating a transaction by optimistically locking a key.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Symfony Lock is useful in this case. You can avoid race condition by using lock on same cache key or database operation.
Just keep in mind once you have `acquire` lock then don't forget to `release` it :)

In case, if you want document then here is the link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html